# Python-dictionary of lists filtering

Tags: python, list, dictionary, filter

I have a python dictionary of lists of phrases I would like to iterate through and print 1. the phrases containing a specified word ('first') and 2. The key they are associated with. I have come up with

```
Mydict = {'One': ['This is the first sentence', ' This is the next sentence after the first'], 'Two': ['This is the second first sentence', ' This is the second second sentence'], 'Three': ['This is the third sentence']}
def search(Mydict, lookup):
    for key, value in Mydict.items():
        for v in value:
            if lookup in v:
                return value, key 

print(search(Mydict, 'first'))
```

Which prints:(['This is the first sentence', ' This is the next sentence after the first'], 'One')

I would like to get the result:
('This is the first sentence','One')
('This is the next sentence after the first','One')
('This is the second first sentence', 'Two')

I am not sure why what I have does not "catch" the third sentence I would like to get in the results. I am also not sure how to break up the lists within the dictionary and access each phrase individually. 
Thank you in advanced for any insight.

Comment: `print([(i, k) for k, v in Mydict.items() for i in v if 'first' in i])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just needed a couple small changes:

1: The reason you were only getting one match is because of your return statement. Since your function returns as soon as it finds a match, you'll only ever get the first match.

2: You were returning value, which is your entire list, instead of v, which is the matching item.

Updated code below

```
Mydict = {'One': ['This is the first sentence', ' This is the next sentence after the first'], 'Two': ['This is the second first sentence', ' This is the second second sentence'], 'Three': ['This is the third sentence']}
def search(Mydict, lookup):
    for key, value in Mydict.items():
        for v in value:
            if lookup in v:
                print((v, key)) 

search(Mydict, 'first')
```